# document.createElement("img") conversion to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, png, createelement

I am finishing my first project, blackjack game, and I need to convert window and document objects to corresponding jQuery. I've figured out most of them with an exception of document.createElement("img").
The code in question is as follows:

```
let cardImg = document.createElement("img");
let card = deck.pop();
cardImg.src = "./cards/" + card + ".png";
yourSum += getValue(card);
yourAces += ValueOfAce(card);
$("#PLAYERcards").append(cardImg)
```

In this code the new card is added, after which the values are computed.

What I've tried is:

```
let card = deck.pop();
let cardImg = $(".img").attr("src", "./cards/" + card + ".png");
yourSum += getValue(card);
yourAces += ValueOfAce(card);
$("#PLAYERcards").append(cardImg);
```

The code does add a new card value to the player's total, and the messages come up when the player has exceeded the total of 21 but the new card image doesn't show. Visually, it looks like player has only 2 cards!!

I'm sure that's something very simple but I'm awfully new to jQuery and would appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: `$(".img")` is a selector - it will select an element with class=img (already) within the DOM.  To create elements in jquery, use HTML:   `cardImg = $("<img>")`

Comment: That did the magic. Thank you!